# MySQL query with GET

Tags: php, sql

Hi below is a sql query that does not function correctly. 
This query below should show 1 invoice of the current selected customer. But somehow I can not manage to make this query work like shown below.

```
<?php
$id = (ISSET($_GET['id'])) ? intval($_GET['id']):0;
$clientnumber= (ISSET($_GET['clientnumber'])) ? intval($_GET['clientnumber']):0;

$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM customers AS a 
            inner join invoices AS b on a . '$clientnumber' = b . '$clientnumber'
                and a . '$id' != b . '$id'"; 

$result = $conn->query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$query=getenv(QUERY_STRING);
parse_str($query);

?>

<?php while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {?>
```

Echo sql results:

```
SELECT * 
FROM customers AS a 
    inner join invoices AS b on a.'0' = b.'0' 
        and a.'4' != b.'4'
```

Comment: what is the actual result ?

Comment: R u getting an error message? You also need to provide some sample data.

Comment: what is the current output/result? Are there any errors?

Comment: @Mo, Blank page

Comment: I doubt `0` is a valid field name in mysql!? What does `$sql` look like when you echo it?

Comment: And I know you never get an id of `0`

Comment: @Jeff let me check.

Comment: show you tables schema , i mean cutomer and invoces

Comment: adn what is the relation between customer and invoices . is it one to one  ?

Comment: If it's a blank page, it could be returning a 500 error. Check the Network tab of your developer console to see what the status code of the request is, and if it is a 500, check your server error logs for more information.

Comment: I have edit my question and put in sql output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Although you should use prepared statements**, I think the problem is that you need to check the column in the customers table matches the columns in the invoices table and not the value your looking for.  The names of the columns I'm not sure about, but your matching the invoice is for the client and then in the WHERE clause you check that the client number is the one your looking for...

```
 SELECT * 
    FROM customers AS a 
    inner join invoices AS b on a.clientnumber = b.clientnumber
            and b.invoiceid = $id
    where a.clientnumber = $clientnumber
```

To work without the ID, then try

```
 SELECT * 
    FROM customers AS a 
    inner join invoices AS b on a.clientnumber = b.clientnumber
    where a.clientnumber = $clientnumber
```

If your clientnumber column is a character field...

```
    where a.clientnumber = '$clientnumber'
```

If this still isn't returning rows, try changing the inner join to...

```
left join invoices AS b on a.clientnumber = b.clientnumber
```

This allows it to find customers where there isn't a matching invoice.

Comment: Let's forget the $id. The strange thing here is that in table invoices and table customers there are same columns in each table named clientnumer and they are unique. This should just work without $id. But the query returns always (0) when it comes to clientnumber.

Comment: And I must say. The query (mine) does work without the strings. But this outputs all connected rows (clientnumbers) inside the while loop. So thats not what I want. So I want to fix this with GET as the clientnumber is in the link

Comment: I've updated with some more code examples.  But I would also recommend changing `select *` to `select a.clientnumber, ...` - so specify the fields your after rather than use *

Comment: The query without the $id does work inside MySQL. But still gives clientnumber''0" on the web

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with the GET? im right now on: /edit.php?id=5/clientnumber=349

Comment: It would normally be `id=5&clientnum` - with an `&` and not an `/`

Comment: Nigel, thats it man oh wauw how can I not see that. It works now!